# How can I reposition an ImageView without losing Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, xcode6

I'm making a single view application game in Xcode 6. I have created a UIImageView and declared it in my .h file as *sphere

```
    IBOutlet UIImageView *sphere;
```

Then in my .m file, I use the following code to have it place at a random position when an object intersects with it.

```
-(void)PlaceSphere{

sphereX = arc4random() %492;
sphereX = sphereX + 34;
sphereY = arc4random() %249;
sphereY = sphereY + 39;

sphere.center = CGPointMake(sphereX, sphereY);

}
```

//Further down

```
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(_ball.frame, sphere.frame)){
    [self PlaceSphere];
```

However, my issue is that in iOS8, using auto layout...when the sphere moves to another location it will flash to a new location and then move back to the original spot on the story board. How would I fix this?

I also experience this with my ball that moves around where the original ball flashes where it was placed on the storyboard. Is there a way I can fix this and still use auto layout?

Thank you

I'm working without auto layout now and the simulator using the iPhone 6 looks fine... so does it matter if I have auto layout if it is just a single view app as long as I use the auto resizing options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an outlet for a constraint in code, like any other interface element. And you can change its value in code to position the view.

So to do this, your view should have x and y position constraints (leading space to superview, top space to superview for example). You select the constraints in the storyboard, as if they were a view, and create outlets for it in the view controller code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *leftConstraint;
```

now you can change the value with the "constant" attribute:

```
self.topConstraint.constant = 39 + (arc4random() %249);
```

There are other ways to do it, but for me this is the best one if you are using auto-layout.

---

As for your other question, "does it matter if I use auto-layout?", that's a personal choice! But for me it's well worth it, as it makes it much easier to support landscape mode and devices with different screen sizes.